# flutter questions when i upgrade to new version

Tags: flutter

```
The argument type 'Int32List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 
'Uint16List'
 - 'Int32List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
 - 'Uint16List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Uint16List'.
    indices: _indices, textureCoordinates: _uvBuffer);
             ^
```

Compiler failed on `$HOME/xun/lib/main.dart`
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.

flutter doctor is no issues

but when flutter run display this issue?

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please update your problem to include the bit of code that causes this error. The error is caused by you are trying to create a list of unsigned integers (only positive numbers) from a list being able to contain signed integers (negative values).

Answer (score 1):

Locally changing line 875 to Uint16List _indices; and line 936 to Uint16List.fromList(triangles); temporarily solves the issue and allows you to run the app, even though it may not be the best solution (not familiar with Flare data).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's the cause of your error, however if you are using `flare_flutter` library, upgrade it to the latest version.

Comment: Part of this could be seen as an answer. Keep that, but move the rest into a comment, please. You can comment on your own answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the Depndency in Pubspec.yaml  but this i tried it only in flutter 1.5.4hotfix sdk

flare_flutter: ^1.5.4

change to

flare_flutter: <= 1.5.0